# String manipulation in AppleScript

Tags: string, applescript, data-manipulation

I have the challenge in AppleScript to manipulate a string as follows:

- Base string is an email recipient display name, say: `First Last (first.last@hotmail.com)`
- I'd like to "trim" the display name to remove the actual email address in the brackets
- The desired result should be `First Last` - so the space in front of the first bracket needs to be removed.

What is the best and most efficient way to do this in AppleScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set theSample to "First Last (first.last@hotmail.com)"

return trimEmailAddress(theSample)
-->Result: "First Last"

on trimEmailAddress(sourceAddress)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {" ("}
    set addressParts to (every text item in sourceAddress) as list
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    set nameOnly to item 1 of addressParts

    return nameOnly
end trimEmailAddress
```

Comment: Great solution. The extraction of the name-only part can be simplified to `set nameOnly to first text item of sourceAddress`, obviating the need for the auxiliary statements involving `addressParts`.

Answer (score 5):

I'd also use offsets. `text 1 thru 2 of "xyz"` is equivalent to `items 1 thru 2 of "xyz" as string`.

```
set x to "First Last (first.last@hotmail.com)"
set pos to offset of " (" in x
{text 1 thru (pos - 1) of x, text (pos + 2) thru -2 of x}
```

As far as I know, [you don't have to restore text item delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598385/is-restoring-text-item-delimiters-or-adding-applescripts-necessary).

```
set x to "First Last (first.last@hotmail.com)"
set text item delimiters to {" (", ")"}
set {fullname, email} to text items 1 thru 2 of x
```

If others were searching about string manipulation in general, here are methods for replacing and splitting text and joining lists:

```
on replace(input, x, y)
    set text item delimiters to x
    set ti to text items of input
    set text item delimiters to y
    ti as text
end replace

on split(input, x)
    if input does not contain x then return {input}
    set text item delimiters to x
    text items of input
end split

on join(input, x)
    set text item delimiters to x
    input as text
end join
```

String comparisons ignore case by default:

```
"A" is "a" -- true
"ab" starts with "A" -- true
considering case
    "A" is "a" -- false
    "ab" starts with "A" -- false
end considering
```

Reversing text:

```
reverse of items of "esrever" as text
```

You can use do shell script to change the case of text:

`do shell script "printf %s " & quoted form of "aä" & " | LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 tr [:lower:] [:upper:]" without altering line endings`

echo interprets escape sequences by default in OS X's /bin/sh. You could also use `shopt -u xpg_echo; echo -n` instead of `printf %s`. `LC_CTYPE=UTF-8` makes character classes include some non-ASCII characters. If `without altering line endings` is left out, linefeeds are replaced with carriage returns and a newline at the end of the output is removed.

`paragraphs of` splits strings around \n, \r, and \r\n. It doesn't strip delimiters.

```
paragraphs of ("a" & linefeed & "b" & return & "c" & linefeed)
-- {"a", "b", "c", ""}
```

The plain text version of the clipboard uses CR line endings. This converts line endings to LF:

```
set text item delimiters to linefeed
(paragraphs of (get the clipboard as text)) as text
```

`Unicode text` has been equivalent with `text` and `string` since [10.5](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/AppleScript/RN-AppleScript/RN-10_5/RN-10_5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000982-CH105-SW1):

> There is no longer a distinction between Unicode and non-Unicode text. There is exactly one text class, named “text”: that is, class of "foo" returns text.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a simpler solution like this:

```
set theSample to "First Last (first.last@hotmail.com)"

on trimEmailAddress(sourceAddress)
    set cutPosition to (offset of " (" in sourceAddress) - 1
    return text 1 thru cutPosition of sourceAddress
end trimEmailAddress

return trimEmailAddress(theSample)
-->  "First Last"
```

Comment: > text 1 thru 2 of "xyz" is equivalent to items 1 thru 2 of "xyz" as string
                                                                                       
Oh! Thanks Lauri for the tip, didn't know this one!!