# Using Applescript to parsing this paragraph

Tags: string, applescript

have anyone know how to convert this paragraphs

```
173.252.100.26 abc.com
173.252.100.26 xyz.com
173.252.100.26 uio.com
```

to

```
\\n173.252.100.26\\abc.com\\n173.252.100.26\\xyz.com\\n173.252.100.26\\uio.com\\n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set input to "173.252.100.26 abc.com
173.252.100.26 xyz.com
173.252.100.26 uio.com"

set text item delimiters to "\\\\n"
"\\\\n" & paragraphs of input as text & "\\\\n"
```

[Restoring text item delimiters is not necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598385/is-restoring-text-item-delimiters-or-adding-applescripts-necessary) as far as I know.