# Error making folders in Applescript

Tags: applescript, directory

So, i'm getting an error while running this:

```
    on hazelProcessFile(theFile)
set text item delimiters to ":"
set filename to last text item of (theFile as text)
set text item delimiters to "."
if filename contains "." then
    set base to text items 1 thru -2 of filename as text
    set extension to "." & text item -1 of filename
else
    set base to filename
    set extension to ""
end if
set text item delimiters to {"720p", "HDTV", "x264", "IMMERSE", "-", "E01", "…", "E02", "EVOLVE"}
set ti to text items of base
set text item delimiters to ""
set newbase to ti as text
set newbase to Replace(newbase, "S0", "Season ")
set newbase to Replace(newbase, ".", " ")
set newbase to Replace(newbase, "   ", "")
set newbase to Replace(newbase, "  ", "")
set folderLocation to "/Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Series/"
set folderName to newbase as text
tell application "Finder"
    if newbase contains "Season" then
        if not (exists folder (POSIX file "/Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Series/" & newbase as text)) then
            set p to path to "/Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Series/"
            --make new folder at p with properties {name:newbase}
            make new folder with properties {name:folderName, location:p}
        else
            move theFile to POSIX file "/Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Series/" & newbase as text
            set name of result to newbase
        end if
    else
        move theFile to POSIX file "/Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Filmes/"
    end if
end tell
end hazelProcessFile

on Replace(input, x, y)
    set text item delimiters to x
    set ti to text items of input
    set text item delimiters to y
    ti as text
end Replace
```

Specifically in the part where it is suposed to create a folder if it doesnt exists (its purpose is to automatically sort tv series episodes).

Log file:

```
NSLocalizedDescription = "Finder got an error: Can\U2019t make \"/Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Series/\" into type constant.";
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Can\U2019t make \"/Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Series/\" into type constant.";
    OSAScriptErrorAppAddressKey = "<NSAppleEventDescriptor: [0x0,c00c \"Finder\"]>";
    OSAScriptErrorAppNameKey = Finder;
    OSAScriptErrorBriefMessageKey = "Can\U2019t make \"/Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Series/\" into type constant.";
    OSAScriptErrorExpectedTypeKey = "<NSAppleEventDescriptor: 'enum'>";
    OSAScriptErrorMessageKey = "Finder got an error: Can\U2019t make \"/Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Series/\" into type constant.";
    OSAScriptErrorNumberKey = "-1700";
    OSAScriptErrorOffendingObjectKey = "<NSAppleEventDescriptor: 'utxt'(\"/Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Series/\")>";
    OSAScriptErrorRangeKey = "NSRange: {0, 0}";
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

EDIT:

So, @lauri helped me with the moving part, the only thing wrong is that the file is copied, not moved, meaning the original file stays in the same place. I want it trashed or copleteley moved. Any ideas?

EDIT 2:

So, I've implemented what @lauri suggested and I still have an error (on the mv command), any ideas?

```
    on hazelProcessFile(theFile)
    set text item delimiters to ":"
    set filename to last text item of (theFile as text)
    set text item delimiters to "."
    if filename contains "." then
        set base to text items 1 thru -2 of filename as text
        set extension to "." & text item -1 of filename
    else
        set base to filename
        set extension to ""
    end if
    set text item delimiters to {"WEB.DL.DD5.1.H.264.HWD", "WEB-DL.AAC2.0.H.264-NTb", "WEB-DL.DD5.1.H.264-CtrlHD", "WEB.DL.DD5.1.H.264", "PMP", "720p", "HDTV", "x264", "IMMERSE", "-", "E01", "…", "E02", "EVOLVE", "DIMENSION", "E03", "E04", "E05", "E06", "E07", "E08", "E09", "E10", "E11", "E12", "E13", "E14", "E15", "E16", "E17", "E18", "E19", "E20", "E21", "E22", "E23", "E24", "E25", "E26", "E27", "E28", "E29", "E30", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "FoV", "FOV", "fov", "1080p", "X264", "AFG", "afg", "xvid", "XviD", "XVID", "INTERNAL", "PROPER", "FQM", "fqm", "LOL", "lol", "REWARD", "reward", "WEB", "DL", "AAC2", "H.264", "NTb", "CtrlHD", "DD5", "eztv", "EZTV", "WEB", "VTV", "mSD", "CTU", "hdtv", "evolve", "immerse", "+", "PublicHD", "HWD"}
    set ti to text items of base
    set text item delimiters to ""
    set newbase to ti as text
    set newbase to Replace(newbase, "S0", "Season ")
    set newbase to Replace(newbase, "S1", "Season 1")
    set newbase to Replace(newbase, "S2", "Season 2")
    set newbase to Replace(newbase, ".", " ")
    set newbase to Replace(newbase, "    ", "")
    set newbase to Replace(newbase, "   ", "")
    set newbase to Replace(newbase, "  ", "")
    set folderLocation to "/Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Series"
    set folderName to newbase as text
    tell application "Finder"
        if newbase contains "Season" then
            if not (exists folder (POSIX file "/Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Series/" & newbase as text)) then

                -- make new folder at POSIX file "/Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Series/" with properties {name:newbase as text}
                -- move theFile to POSIX file "/Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Series/" & newbase as text
                do shell script "d=/Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Series/" & quoted form of newbase & "
                mkdir -p \"$d\"
                mv " & quoted form of POSIX path of theFile & " $d"



            else
                -- move theFile to POSIX file "/Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Series/" & newbase as text
                do shell script "d=/Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Series/" & quoted form of newbase & "
                mv " & quoted form of POSIX path of theFile & " $d"

                set name of result to newbase
            end if
        else
            -- move theFile to POSIX file "/Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Filmes/"
            do shell script "mv " & quoted form of POSIX path of theFile & " /Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Filmes/"
        end if
    end tell
end hazelProcessFile

on Replace(input, x, y)
    set text item delimiters to x
    set ti to text items of input
    set text item delimiters to y
    ti as text
end Replace
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `path to` with `POSIX file` and use an `at` specifier for the location:

```
tell application "Finder"
    make new folder at POSIX file "/tmp" with properties {name:"new folder"}
end tell
```

FWIW, this question was follow-up to [Applescript error while trying to move files with hazel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501501/applescript-error-while-trying-to-move-files-with-hazel).

Apparently the move command copies files when the target is on a different volume. You could use do shell script instead:

```
if newbase contains "Season" then
    do shell script "d=/Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Series/" & quoted form of newbase & "
mkdir -p \"$d\"
mv " & quoted form of POSIX path of theFile & " $d"
else
    do shell script "mv " & quoted form of POSIX path of theFile & " /Volumes/LaCie/Midia/Filmes/"
end if
```

Comment: Thats perfect! Only thing is, when I do this, the file doesn't get moved, it just gets copied, meaning that the original file stays in the same folder as it used, triggering it to be moved constantly... Any ideas how to fix ta @lauri?

Comment: I've updated the answer with the new script, on wich i get an error, any ideas?

Comment: I've updated the answer with the new script, on wich i get an error, any ideas @lauri?