# Automator replacing character with apple script or shell script

Tags: shell, applescript, automator

I am creating an automator process but I need to take string and replace all the "\" characters with the character "/". Working with a buddy we decided to use a shell script but I am open to anything to do this. With the line we wrote, we just get an error.

```
set input to (do shell script "echo \"" & input & "\" | sed 's/\\\\//g'")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
set myString to "This\\is\\my\\string" -- really This\is\my\string

set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "\\"}
set myString to text items of myString
set text item delimiters to "/"
set myString to myString as text
set text item delimiters to TID

return myString
```

or

```
set input to "This\\is\\my\\string" -- really This\is\my\string
set output to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of input & " | sed 's/[\\]/\\//g'"
```

Comment: Perfect, I like applescript more anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, [it is no longer necessary to restore text item delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598385), so adayzdone's example can be simplified to something like this:

```
set s to "aa\\bb\\cc"
set text item delimiters to "\\"
set ti to text items of s
set text item delimiters to "/"
ti as text -- "aa/bb/cc"
```

`do shell script` uses `/bin/sh`, which is a version of bash that starts in POSIX mode and has a few other changes as well. One of them is that `xpg_echo` is enabled by default, so that `echo` interprets escape sequences like `\t`:

```
do shell script "echo " & quoted form of "ss\\tt" & " | xxd -p" -- "737309740a"
```

You can just use `printf %s` instead:

```
do shell script "printf %s " & quoted form of "ss\\tt" & "|tr \\\\ /" -- "s/t"
```

If you don't add a `without altering line endings` specifier, `do shell script` converts line endings to CR and chomps one newline from the end of the output.

Comment: If it is possible that the OP is posting a piece of a larger code, it is much safer to restore TID to their original values. The extra few lines don't add to execution time and I believe restoring TIDs is a good practice to avoid problems in bigger scripts.

Comment: +1 for the `do shell script` background info; see my answer for bypassing the `echo` problem with a here-string.

Answer (score 0):

@Lauri Ranta's `do shell script` pointers are helpful, but a simple variation of the original command does the trick:

Even though `do shell script` invokes `bash` as `sh` and therefore in a mode it calls 'POSIX mode', many bash-specific features are still available, among them the so called *here-string* to feed a string directly to a command via stdin, e.g.: `cat <<<'Print this'`:

Thus, by using a here-string - passed with `quoted form of` from AppleScript, which is always advisable - the `echo` problem is bypassed:

```applescript
# Sample input.
set input to "a\\\\b" # equivalent of" 'a\\b'

# Remove all `\` characters; returns 'ab'
set input to (do shell script "sed 's/\\\\//g' <<<" & quoted form of input)
```

---

Alternative, using `tr -d` instead of `sed`:

```applescript
 set input to (do shell script "tr -d '\\\\' <<<" & quoted form of input)
```