# Applescript - Replace character "Cant get every item of alias"

Tags: applescript

Below is my code to rename file. The code basically check for special character and replace with **`"_"`**(underscore).

Code

```
set thefile to choose file

    set Filename to my replace_chars(thefile, "   ", " ")
    set Filename to my replace_chars(thefile, "  ", " ")
    set Filename to my replace_chars(thefile, " ", "_")
    set Filename to my replace_chars(thefile, ",", "_")
    set Filename to my replace_chars(thefile, "!", "_")
    set Filename to my replace_chars(thefile, "~", "_")
    set Filename to my replace_chars(thefile, "*", "_")
    set Filename to my replace_chars(thefile, "/", "_")
    set Filename to my replace_chars(thefile, ":", "_")
    set Filename to my replace_chars(thefile, "(", "_")
    set Filename to my replace_chars(thefile, ")", "_")
    set Filename to my replace_chars(thefile, "___", "_")
    set Filename to my replace_chars(thefile, "__", "_")

tell application "Finder"

    set the name of file thefile to "Testing.png"
end tell

on replace_chars(this_text, search_string, replacement_string)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the search_string
    set the item_list to every text item of this_text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the replacement_string
    set this_text to the item_list as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return this_text
end replace_chars
```

It throws **`"Cant get every text item of alias"`** Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`choose file` returns an alias. You can get the basename of the file with `tell app "Finder" to name of`:

```
set f to choose file
tell application "Finder" to set n to name of f
set n to replace(n, "a", "b")
tell application "Finder" to set name of f to n

on replace(input, x, y)
    set text item delimiters to x
    set ti to text items of input
    set text item delimiters to y
    ti as text
end replace
```

As far as I know, [restoring text item delimiters property is not necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598385/is-restoring-text-item-delimiters-or-adding-applescripts-necessary) if you don't rely on it later in the same script.

Comment: It may not be necessary, but it's still good practice. Especially in a sub-routine which has no idea what's going on in the code outside of itself.