# Replacing words in Applescript

Tags: macos, text, applescript

I'm back to writing Applescripts. I'm making a script that will Google things for you. Basically, I need to replace all of the spaces with %20. I know a little about text item delimiters, but I don't know how to implement them in this case.

Here's what I got so far:

```
if userInput contains "Google " then set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, {"Google "}}
if length of userInput is greater than or equal to 2 then set resultString to text item 2 of userInput
if userInput contains "Google " then set text item delimiters to TID
set openPage to (resultString as string)
if userInput contains "Google " then do shell script "open http://www.google.com/search?q=" & openPage
```

FYI, the userInput variable is the variable I use when dealing with textboxes.

Thanks

Comment: sure, its been a while since i looked at applescripts too. it would help if you post what you tried so far! or did you want someone to just write the whole script for you!?

Comment: Ok now maybe add code block too (right now it shows all on oneline - i dont think it would be working without editing now)

Comment: Have you looked at this thread and the accepted answer, maybe the same technique works in this situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782688/applescript-replace-character-cant-get-every-item-of-alias

Comment: Yes, I looked at that, but I don't want to use Finder for the task. I heard elsewhere I might able to do this with Applescript's TIDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this script demonstrates the principle of what you’re trying to do:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    display dialog "Search Google for:" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button "OK" with title (the name as text) with icon note giving up after 60
    if the button returned of the result is equal to "OK" then
        set theSearch to the text returned of the result
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to space
        set theSearchList to every text item of theSearch
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "+"
        set theQuery to theSearchList as text
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
        set theLink to "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" & theQuery & "&btnG=Google+Search"
        open location theLink
    end if
end tell
```

However, it’s a lot easier if you just ask an app like BBEdit (or its free version, TextWrangler, which has the same AppleScript dictionary) to do the find and replace for you, because BBEdit is an expert at finding and replacing text, whereas AppleScript by itself is not. AppleScript is a “little language” — it deliberately lacks 95% of the functionality of most programming languages because the functionality is in the apps that you command with AppleScript. In other words, AppleScript expects you to have a text editor with which to process text, therefore AppleScript deliberately doesn’t have the built-in text processing ability of a language like Perl (which you can also use in your AppleScripts.)

So the above script gets a lot shorter, easier to write, easier to read, and easier to understand if you add BBEdit (or the free TextWrangler) into the mix:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    display dialog "Search Google for:" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button "OK" with title (the name as text) with icon note giving up after 60
    if the button returned of the result is equal to "OK" then
        set theSearch to the text returned of the result
        tell application "BBEdit"
            set theQuery to replace " " using "+" searchingString theSearch
        end tell
        set theLink to "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" & theQuery & "&btnG=Google+Search"
        open location theLink
    end if
end tell
```

Also, notice that you don’t have to run a shell script to open a link in a browser. So this line in your script:

```
if userInput contains "Google " then do shell script "open http://www.google.com/search?q=" & openPage
```

… can be written like this:

```
if userInput contains "Google " then open location "http://www.google.com/search?q=" & openPage
```

… or like this:

```
if userInput contains "Google " then
    open location "http://www.google.com/search?q=" & openPage
end if
```

… and you can use the “open location” command with any app, not just Safari. If you tell Finder to “open location” the link will open in your default browser, which might be Chrome.